# 2008R2 DFS репликация прав доступа к папкам

Tags: windows, windows-server, windows-server-2008-r2, dfs

Есть два сервера с DFS. DC1 и DC2. На DC1 висит расшаренная по DFS папка, на DC2 производится репликация. Когда пользователь подключен к DFS на DC2 он не может скинуть файл в разрешенную ему папку, а на DC1 - может. Вкладка "действующие разрешения" показывает что права у пользователя на DC2 имеются.
Куда смотреть? Где копать? 
server 2008R2 DFSR

Answer (score 1):

Решено. В свойствах сервера пространства имен DC2 нужно задать те же разрешения общего что и у DC1.